# Kakashi's face without the mask

Tags: naruto

I was wondering if Kakashi's face has ever been revealed without the mask. I finished the manga way back in 2014. And decided to go finish the anime. And the thought came back. So any chance it has ever been revealed and when?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was originally shown in the book *Naruto Exhibition Official Guestbook New Style: Scroll of Wind* (or *Fū no Sho* for short), which was given to the guests who attended a Naruto exhibition held in Japan on April 25, 2015.

Fū no Sho:

[image]

It was then adapted into an anime episode (ep. 469), which you can watch [here](http://www.crunchyroll.com/naruto-shippuden/episode-469-a-special-mission-716115).

By the way, this is how he looks like:

[image]

Comment: So fine.  he looks rather good

Comment: @Hansen, I know right. He's really handsome!

Comment: Thanks again. @Akira_Mahisaseru... I'm gonna watch the episode and draw him.

Comment: @Hansen, (just a random fact) you can see he doesn't have the Sharingan... Something that bothers me every damn day!!!

Comment: Oh. Right. I noticed too. If you read the wiki, it says he's incorrectedly depicted. Maybe a graphic error? Lol. And also the person he was acting as, Sukea or something like that, also didn't have the sharigan. It could have been contact lenses or something. 

Comment: @Hansen, he was using contacts when he was dressed as Sukea... When I first read the chapter I noticed right away, and it really bothered me...

Comment: Oh. You have a copy of the omake?

Comment: I mean Fu no Sho? I dunno. But in the anime, since like there were a lot of dream filler episodes, something like popped up and it didn't really seem necessary to put in the sharingan since at the point of that battle, his sharingan had been removed and naruto had given him a normal eye back

Comment: But it's certainly creepy if you think about it. 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49073/discussion-between-akira-mahisaseru-and-hansen).

Answer (score 4):

Yes , it was revealed only in anime in `469 episode`

You can watch it here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ns3Izj4Ul4U

Comment: What arc is this episode?

Comment: its not in a arc it is a filler episode

Comment: Oh. Yeah. I figured. But around what arc was this filler episode?

Comment: Was it during the infinite tsukinomi?

Comment: yes it is in the kagura arc only

Comment: you might want to add the screenshot here as well

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Episode 469 of Naruto Shippuden. He show his face twice in that episode